# How to create unique shapes or UIViews in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I don't really have any knowledge of drawing in Swift, but I'm looking to create part of my app background that's slightly different to a square. See the image below for what I'm trying to make:

[image]

The idea is that this will sit at the top of the screen, and be nothing more than a background. It'll stretch half way down the screen. I'll then add an image over the top etc. I would need the point at the bottom of the square to always sit in the middle of the screen.

Can I make this shape/UIView in Swift by code? And if so, how?

Or, is it better to just create this as an image and do it that way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Can I make this shape/UIView in Swift by code? And if so, how?

Views are always rectangular, but a view's content can be any shape at all and it's background can be transparent, so the visible part of a view can be anything you can draw.

There are *a lot* of ways to draw something in iOS. It's usually best to start with the highest level tool that'll work for you and move down to a lower level when you need more control. With that in mind, I'd suggest starting by creating a view that draws your pentagon using a `UIBezierPath`. The (Swift 5) code for this is very simple:

```swift
class PentagonView : UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let size = self.bounds.size
        let h = size.height * 0.85      // adjust the multiplier to taste

        // calculate the 5 points of the pentagon
        let p1 = self.bounds.origin
        let p2 = CGPoint(x:p1.x + size.width, y:p1.y)
        let p3 = CGPoint(x:p2.x, y:p2.y + h)
        let p4 = CGPoint(x:size.width/2, y:size.height)
        let p5 = CGPoint(x:p1.x, y:h)

        // create the path
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: p1)
        path.addLine(to: p2)
        path.addLine(to: p3)
        path.addLine(to: p4)
        path.addLine(to: p5)
        path.close()

        // fill the path
        UIColor.red.set()
        path.fill()
    }
}
```

And now you can use that view anywhere in your UI:
[image: PentagonView]

If you want to add a 150x150px `PentagonView` to your view controller's main view at coordinates (100, 200), you could put the following in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let pg = PentagonView(frame:CGRect(x:100, y:200, width:150, height:150))
self.view.addSubview(pg)
```

Or, you could also add a `PentagonView` to some view in your storyboard by dropping in a `UIView` of the right size and then changing it's class to `PentagonView`.

> Or, is it better to just create this as an image and do it that way?

If you've fully described your requirement, then no, I don't think so: the image itself will probably be a lot larger than the code that draws it, and the code that I've given above will work at any size you choose. On the other hand, if you're going to add a lot of complex detail, and if the image only needs to appear at one size, then it might be easier to create it once in a drawing program and store that work as an image. Like I said above, there are a lot of options for drawing in iOS; which you choose should be determined by your needs.

Comment: Thanks for this! I can kinda make sense of each step so thanks for the comments! I have created a new .Swift file, and added that code, then in the VC's .Swift file, in `viewDidLoad` method, I added `let BG = PentagonView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: CGSize(width: 250, height: 250)))` - But when i run the app, nothing shows. There are no errors in Xcode, just nothing shows.

Comment: @Nick89 Sorry if that's unclear -- I wrote the code above in a playground, where all you really need to do to see the result is instantiate the view. To use in an app, you'd need to create an instance of `PentagonView` somewhere and then add it to a view hierarchy. The easiest way to do that is probably to just drop a `PentagonView` in one of your views in your storyboard, if you're using one.

Comment: Hi, Sorry i'm not following :( I've never done anything drawing wise before so struggling how to set this up. I added the code into a new file called `CreateShape.swift` and I need to add it my view controller, which has a file connected to it called `mainVC.swift`. Could you help show me in code how I'd set this up. I'm looking to do a lot more with drawing so would love to understand how to do it! Thanks in advance

Comment: @Nick89 You should take a look at the Creating a View section of the [UIView reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html). After your `let BG = ...` line, add another line: `self.view.addSubview(BG)`. That should do what you want because `self.view` is the view controller's main view. You call `addSubview()` to add `BG` as a subview of that view. If you want to change the position or size of the `PentagonView`, change the frame rectangle where you create `BG`.

Comment: Ah i get it! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: and if you add a shadow to such view it will have rectangle shape. The answer is incorrect!

Comment: @Gargo I've written several thousand answers over the years, and every one of them could be considered "incorrect" if you take it out of context or add conditions after the fact. My answer demonstrates using a bezier path to draw a pentagon in a view that could be used as a background, which is what the OP asked about. If you want to draw a pentagon for some other use, you might choose to draw it in a different context. If you want to apply a shadow, you could take the path construction code from this answer and use it to draw into a layer instead of a view, after which you can add a shadow.

Answer (score 4):

**Caleb's** answer updated to **Swift 5**:

```swift
class PentagonView : UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let size = self.bounds.size
        let h = size.height * 0.85      // adjust the multiplier to taste

        // calculate the 5 points of the pentagon
        let p1 = self.bounds.origin
        let p2 = CGPoint(x:p1.x + size.width, y:p1.y)
        let p3 = CGPoint(x:p2.x, y:p2.y + h)
        let p4 = CGPoint(x:size.width/2, y:size.height)
        let p5 = CGPoint(x:p1.x, y:h)

        // create the path
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: p1)
        path.addLine(to: p2)
        path.addLine(to: p3)
        path.addLine(to: p4)
        path.addLine(to: p5)
        path.close()

        // fill the path
        UIColor.red.set()
        path.fill()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to tackle this is not by creating a view (`UIView`) but a layer (`CAShapeLayer`). You can create a CAShapeLayer from a path, thus describing your shape with vectors (as opposed to a bitmap).

There are many tutorials about CAShapeLayer that will show you code for achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best if you loaded an image from file of the shape onto a UIImageView, especially if its just a background. You can then constraint the bottom of the view to the middle of your app. You might also be able to do some tweaking of the view's CALayer property to achieve your effect however.

Comment: With an image, you’d have to maintain different versions of the asset for different screen sizes and resolutions. This is pretty easy to do in code and entirely avoid that problem.

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon I would argue that an entirely red shape like this could just be scaled down reasonably without much loss in quality by Xcode itself.