# Custom UIView losing animation capability on draw func override

Tags: swift, uikit

I made a custom class nested from UIView and override `draw` method to draw a custom shape on layer and thus my view stopped to animate through `UIView.animate` method.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var shapeView: CustomShapeView = {
        let view = CustomShapeView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(shapeView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            shapeView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            shapeView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            shapeView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            shapeView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        self.shapeView.backgroundColor = .green

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.shapeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        })
    }

    class CustomShapeView: UIView {
        override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        }
    }
}
```

I've found a method to add my shape to the layer by `view.layer.addSublayer` method although I'm curious – why my view becomes static (can't be animated) on `draw` method override.

Can somebody explain this?
I think this might be useful (especially to novice developers), because I see here and there code examples ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777992/how-to-create-unique-shapes-or-uiviews-in-swift)) which advise such logic.

Comment: Please update your question with relevant code fully demonstrating your issue.

Comment: Your update doesn't show enough code or explain what the actual problem is. Why do you first set `triangleView.backgroundColor` but then try to animate `triangleView.layer.backgroundColor`? Where's your use of `addSublayer`? Why override `draw` and mess with layers? Do one or the other.

Comment: @HangarRash you can check the updated question's code now

Comment: Your question still talks about layers but there is no use of layers in your posted code. You still don't mention what the actual problem is. You mention it stopped animating. But the only animating you do is a change of background color. And you don't show the custom `draw` method. So your question still provides no useful information to help. You need to post code that can be copied and pasted to fully replicate your issue, along with a clearer explanation of the exact problem you are seeing.

Comment: @HangarRash The title and the sentence "why my view becomes static (can't be animated) on draw method override" is the main question. The backstory (and reason of draw func override) I told at the start. And also added examples when this method is suggested to be overridden but without mentioning this consequence.

Comment: @HangarRash I already provided the code needed to recreate this error. You can create a new iOS project on UIKit, paste the code into ViewController and voila.

Answer (score 1):

Once you override the `draw` method of a view, any attempt to animate the view's `backgroundColor` just results in the new color appearing immediately.

The workaround is to change the following:

```
self.shapeView.backgroundColor = .green

UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: { [weak self] in
    self?.shapeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
})
```

to:

```
self.shapeView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor

UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: { [weak self] in
    self?.shapeView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
})
```

Changing the background color of the view's layer, instead of the view itself, allows the animation to complete as desired.

Comment: can you, please, explain why UIView loses its animation capability when draw function is overridden?

Comment: It doesn't lose all animation. Most animatable properties still work, such as `alpha`, for example. It's just `backgroundColor` that stops working. My best guess is that a property like `backgroundColor` loses meaning once you have a custom `draw` implementation because now the custom `draw` becomes responsible for filling the background.